# Keyframes rotation jumping around in IE 10

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, internet-explorer-10

I'm using a basic CSS loading indicator, based on the one from w3schools. It works great except when using IE 10, where it jumps around. 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader

Does anyone know of a workaround for IE10?

```
.loader {
   ...
   border-radius: 50%;
   animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
   ...
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with Document mode using developer tools in IE11.

I notice that it shows the result correctly but it also shows a popup to allow block content.

If you allow it then code get break.

with other older versions of IE it not showing any pop up but also not working.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

So You can try to make a test without allowing content to check whether it is working with IE10 or not.

Comment: Thank you for testing! Unfortunately, it seems the Emulator doesn't produce the same behavior as the real IE 10. I also tested using another machine using the IE11-Emulator, and js errors appeared on the page instead ( and the spinner didn't jump around ).